# Компоновка, компиляция

Tags: c, компиляция

Можно объяснить, что такое препроцессор, компиляция, линковщик, как происходит сборка файлов, пошаговые этапы?

Comment: Компилер свой хотите написать? ;-)

Comment: Для того чтобы объяснить такие базовые понятия, нужно опираться на какие-либо ваши общие знания, но из вашего вопроса вообще не понятен ваш уровень знаний (что вы вообще заете о компьютерах и программировании).

Comment: ну напишите как вы понимаете,уровень знаний более менее,хочу подробнее разобраться

Comment: вы знаете что собой представлиет выполняемая программа (exe в Windows)? Что делает системный загрузчик? Если вы не уверенны в этих знаниях, то начать я бы порекомендовал с этого. Поняв этот этап, можно на следующем понять, что такое dll. После этого вы легко поймете, что такое примерно obj файл и поймете функции компилятора и линковщика. Иначе вы будете читать правильное объяснение, что есть что (см. ответ avp'а) и все равно ничего не понимать.

Comment: Вы, кстати, работаете под Windows или нет? Используете ли Visual Studio? Если да, то какой версии? Просто не возможно разобраться без конкретных примеров. Многие утилиты анализирующие кор помогают разобраться в содержимом exe, dll, obj и пр.

Comment: пишу в sublime компилирую через mingw, oc Windows

Comment: я мог бы вам кое что объяснить на примере Visual Studio (можно считать безплатно Community версию с https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-RU/). Для начала можно взять проект из [моего старого ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3381135/315935), скомпилировать. Полученная `HelloWorld.exe` должна иметь 3072 байтов. Можно стартовать command prompt Visual Studio, запустить в нем `dumpbin /headers HelloWorld.exe`, затем с ключами `/imports`, `/disasm` или `/all` и разобраться примерно что есть что.

Comment: Важно понять зто в программе уже **виртуальные адреса** от `400000` до `4011D0` и они **не изменятся** при загрузке и выполнении программы. Важно понять, что в прграмме есть несколько байтов  (402000-40200С), которые должны содержать адреса начала кода `lstrlen`, `GetStdHandle` и `WriteConsole` из `KERNEL32.dll`. Эти значения и будет *вписывать* системный загрузчик а затем загрузит 4011A8 (см. entry point) в качестве стартового адреса. Все очень просто, хотя exe содержит еще немного "лишней" информации.

Comment: То исть программа состоит из кусков неизменяемого при загрузе и некоторых изменяемых кусков. Компилятор делает предварительную работу и размещает предварительные результаты в виде связных кусков кода, данных и управляющей информации. Линкер знает этот формат и работает уже блоками соединяя все вместе в новый вормат данных - exe или dll.

Answer (score 7):

Очень коротко.

**Препроцессор** делает текстовые преобразования исходного .c файла (в т.ч. вставляет текст из #include) и результат передается на вход компилятору.

**Компилятор** преобразует свой вход (программу на языке Си) в объектный файл (.o), который содержит константы, машинные команды и таблицу внешних символов (переменные и функции к которым обращается этот исходный код, но которые в нем не определены).

**Линковщик** (редактор связей) на основе результатов компилятора (.o файлы) и известных ему библиотек (по сути это те же .о файлы, но специальным образом скомпонованные) создает исполняемый файл (в винде .exe) или разделяемую библиотеку (в винде .dll, в *nix .so). При этом происходит так называемое разрешение внешних имен, т.е. ранее известные только по именам функции и внешние переменные обретают адреса и в соответствии с этим меняется код объектного файла (сами .o, естественно, не изменяются).

**Системный загрузчик** (часть ядра ОС) читает исполняемый файл в память и проводит окончательную настройку адресов (если требуется), а также связывает этот машинный код с кодом в системных разделяемых библиотеках (они общие для всех программ в системе и их часто используемые части обычно уже подкачаны в память к моменту загрузки Вашей программы).

Вопросы виртуальной памяти (преобразование виртуальных адресов в физические) я тут не рассматривал.