# Как работает компоновка С-приложений?

Tags: c, dll, компиляция, lib, компоновщик

Компилятор выполняет сборку объектных файлов (.obj) в каждом из которых (в начале?) содержится таблица символов, где хранится все глобальные переменные, их значения (если они есть) и адреса объявленных функции. Что же представляет собой остальное содержимое объектного файла? Скомпилированный код. Как он выглядит, если у нас несколько функций? Не сливается же это всё в единую последовательность команд...

Как устроена статическая линковка библиотек? Неразрешённые символы таблицы символов компоновщик ищет в указанных библиотеках. Так понимаю, в библиотеке тоже должно быть указано где находится искомая функция и её размер. Далее функция включается в исполняемый файл. Выходит, .lib не нужно за собой таскать раз функция уже в .exe?

Как устроена динамическая линковка библиотек? ОС должна используя таблицу импорта найти нужные функции в .dll и загрузить эти функции в оперативную память процесса?

Пожалуйста, можно **объяснить** поподробнее обо всех этих вещах и том, что посчитаете относящимся к этому вопросу.

---

**CORRECTED:** Уточняю свои вопросы:

1. *Объектные файлы*. Компилятор выполняет создание объектного файла, который в общем виде представлен заголовком, содержащим различную информацию о программе, и скомпилированным кодом, который так же зависит от RTL и, в зависимости от компилятора, содержит те или иные ссылки на функции из библиотек RTL. Заголовок так же содержит таблицу символов (где находится информация обо всех методах и глобальных переменных (размер, тип, адреса и т.п.), а так же, в случае С++, описания методов классов, запись названий которых осуществляется при помощи декорирования имён ввиду некоторых ограничений на символы (в случае dll, это затрудняет использование классов при явной компоновке, как я понял)). Скомпилированный код просто представлен сплошными инструкциями, которые как-то разделяются по функциям, на начала которых указывают символы в таблице символов. Когда объектных файлов несколько, таблицы символов сливаются, как и код, а из повторяющихся символов выбирается самый "массивный". **Верно ли? Чем вы можете дополнить это?**.
2. *Статическая компоновка*. Неразрешённые символы из таблицы символов объектного файла компоновщик ищет в подключаемых библиотеках. В случае статической компоновки .lib файл используется лишь как ресурс для функций, откуда копируются в целевой .exe их содержимое (**т.е. .lib за собой таскать не надо?**).
3. *Динамическая компоновка*. При динамической линковке, компоновщик помечает неразрешённые символы как IOU ("я тебе должен") (**ищет ли он их определения в указанных .dll? надо же быть уверенным, что такая .dll, которую указал пользователь вообще существует и в ней есть этот метод. Разве нет?**). При запуске .exe ОС подключает нужные .dll (ищет их в нужных местах) и загружает в память. Только, вроде как, при неявной компоновке если какая-то .dll уже есть в памяти, она не будет загружена снова. **Но как ОС знает по какому адресу эта .dll загружена?** **Методы заменяются на ссылки на функции загруженной .dll или как?** При явной загрузке все функции .dll вроде просто выгружаются в память на ровне с функциями самого .exe и в таблице данных есть адреса этих функций в оперативной памяти - **или как это вообще выглядит**? При передаче переменной в метод её имя заменяется на адрес из блока данных? Как это выглядит?

Comment: Тут несколько вопросов, ответ на каждый будет занимать немало места. Ознакомьтесь для начала с форматом OBJ-файлов и с IDA

Comment: Ну мне достаточно общей информации. Не настолько подробно, чтобы написать целую статью как на Хабре.

Comment: Где-то абзацев 3 по каждому вопросу.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Компоновка, компиляция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487001/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @Komdosh, не дубликат. В том вопросе, по сути, только терминология.

Comment: Много писать, действительно, лень. Вы поищите в интернете (наверное что-то приличное д.б. в вике), а потом, что конкретно останется непонятным, спросите.

Comment: @avp А вы не пишите много. Мне не нужна книга вашего авторства. Объясните вопросы так подробно, как посчитаете достаточных в рамках StackOverflow.

Comment: @D.Stark, посмотрел на ваши требования к Бармалею, и что-то пропала охота вам писать...

Comment: @avp Ваше право...

Comment: В стандарте все это не оговорено, так что говорить можно только о конкретном компиляторе, конкретной операционной системе и т.д. Никто не мешает завтра написать компилятор (да и операционную систему), в которой абсолютно все это будет абсолютно не так...

Comment: @Harry Окей. Windows OS, MS Visual C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Извините конечно, но на тему ваших вопросов можно целую книгу написать...

Если очень грубо, то формат объектного файла в целом описывается стандартом [ELF - Executable & Linkable File](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) - по сути это файл с неким заголовком и произвольным набором секций, именование секций вообще говоря зависит от платформы. Для старых Windows программ формат объектных файлов описывается [COFF - Common Object File Format](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) - структурно формат схож с ELF, но он более Windows ориентирован, в то время как ELF - кроссплатформенный.

Если охота поразбираться в кишках - то [велкам сюда](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf)

Comment: Поразбираться не охота и не требуется. Мне нужны общие сведения.

Comment: В вашем ответе не хватает пояснения ключевого вопроса по объектным файлам: как оформляется секция с кодом и разделяются функций. Ясно, что имя каждой функции и адрес на её начало, размер хранится в таблице символов (..и адрес точки входа в заголовке объектного файла). Но как именно эти функции отделяются и выглядят в скомпилированном виде. Вопросы статической и динамической компоновки, а так же "слияния" таблиц символов разных объектных файлов при получении целевого .exe, вообще не рассмотрены.

Comment: Писать неохота - многабукаф :) Читайте мануалы, вгрызайтесь - удачи

Comment: Ну а вы думали зачем я вопрос задал...

Comment: Прямо скажем вопрос не совсем по теме сайта - это не есть вопрос о конкретной проблеме, а вопрос из сорта общеобразовательных

Comment: Букварь лень читать? Да тут по вашей логике всем букварь лень читать,  ведь ответы на почти все вопросы можно найти в разных там документациях, учебниках, мануалах и т.д. Мои вопросы же вполне конкретны (ну по крайней мере, теперь) и я не требую ни от кого лезть в "букварь" за меня. Вопрос для тех, кто может дать ответ не залезая в гугл...