# Класс с векторами. LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall Vector::setvector(double,double,double)" (?setvector@Vector@@QAEXNNN@Z) уже определен в Source.obj

Tags: c++, vector

Было у меня 2 файла: sourse.cpp, vector.cpp. но нужно сделать из vector.cpp vector.cpp и vector.h. в первом файле - реализация, во втором - прототип. 
Вот код:

vector.h - https://hastebin.com/detiqajefa.cpp

sourse.cpp - https://hastebin.com/uzatasinob.cpp

vector.cpp - https://hastebin.com/cuyehiwuyi.cpp

Что я делаю не так? судя по ошибке переменная определена дважды. но я не вижу где
что странно, дал другу этот код, у него работает... 
[image: скрин ошибок]

Comment: sourse.cpp: надо `#include "vector.h"`, а не `#include "vector.cpp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно инклудить `cpp`-файл, это за вас сделает линкер. Каждый `cpp` представляет собой отдельный транслируемый модуль. `.h`- файлы обычно содержат объявления типов, то есть некие контракты, которые связывают реализации (`cpp`).

Почитайте о том, [как работает компоновка приложений в Си](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732168/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), это позволит избежать кучи подобных оплошностей.

Comment: убрал. появилось 18 ошибок с текстом, что класс Vector не определён.

Comment: @OlegBrony, ну так включите хэдер (`vector.h`).

Comment: афигеть... заработало. спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

В файле *source.cpp* Вы включили *vector.cpp*:

```
#include "vector.cpp"
```

Замените на:

```
  #include "vector.h"
```